# Detect stop process Python

Tags: python, c, linux

I have a C program. I want it to run and stop at specific points, and let a python script do some things while it is stopped.

What I did was to put this line at the stopping points in the C program:

```
kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);
```

If my python code has this line:

```
subprocess.call("./prog");
```

It is stuck forever, because the C program is never terminated.

If I use this:

```
subprocess.Popen("./prog");
```

It resumes before the code section was done.

How can I check if the subprocess is stopped?
Or is there another solution?
It is very important for me to keep the C program running.

Thank you,
Marina

Comment: `SIGSTOP` is used to suspend a process until it receives eventually `SIGCONT` signal. It is not clear who sends `SIGCONT` in your case. My answer shows that you don't need the signals to synchronize two processes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's your purpose, if you want to check a subprocess' status, use [`Popen.poll()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll), if you want to wait for it to stop, use [`Popen.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait).

Or you need to check its status periodically? If so, try [`threading.Timer()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html#timer-objects).

Comment: poll returns None.
What I need is to find out when the process is stopped.

Comment: @user1637056 It returns `None` because it hasn't stopped.

Comment: @user1637056 see https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode

Answer (score 0):

To synchronize the execution of your Python script with the child C process, you could use communication e.g., write a byte to stdout `putchar('\0')` in C program in the place where you want it to stop and wait while Python does something and try to read back a char `getchar()` to continue execution and in reverse in the Python script: read a byte, start doing something, and write byte to signal C program to continue:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# start child process, do not block Python
p = Popen("./prog", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=0)
while p.poll() is None: # while C program is running
    # block here until C program writes a byte and flushes its stdout buffer
    if not p.stdout.read(1): # EOF
        break
    # .. do something while C program waits
    p.stdin.write(b'\0') # signal C program to continue
```

To unbuffer stdout in C, call at the very beginning of the C program:

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL,_IONBF,0);
```

Otherwise Python program won't see any output until you call `fflush()` explicitly or the corresponding buffer overflows.